# Binding prefix to C-Space in tmux doesn't work when you have nested sessions

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I've been using `C-Space` as my binding for the tmux prefix for a long time and its been working great. Recently though, I've been trying to make it work with nested sessions, and it doesn't work at all. The problem is the following:

If I bind prefix to something more normal like `C-a`, I can have nested sessions and type `C-a` `a` to send the prefix to the nested session, and `C-a` to send the prefix to the outer session. This is normal tmux usage and what you would expect. For some reason this doesn't work if the prefix is `C-Space`.

Tried doing things like `unbind Space` with no success.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```bash
# Set prefix to Ctrl-Space
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind C-Space send-prefix
```